# Flexbox child overflow auto to respect parent height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like a grandchild from a flex container to have its max height contained by the total height of container (100%) minus the other child height, and then have scrollbars appear when the grandchild has reached its max size.

Here is a fiddle to show it, basically I do not want the list items to overflow the green container.

https://jsfiddle.net/gcdzL3jn/2/

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

#main {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#panel {
  height: 100%;
}

#panel-top {
  height: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#panel-bottom-overflow {
  border-style: solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="panel-top">
        Top Panel
      </div>
      <div id="panel-bottom-overflow">
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a height for the overflowing element. With a height limit in place, the `overflow` property can be triggered. Add this to your code:

```
#panel-bottom-overflow { height: calc(100% - 80px); }
```

---

Your green container (`#main`) has one child (`#panel`). Both elements are set to `height: 100%`.

The child element has two children: `#panel-top` and `#panel-bottom-overflow`.

`#panel-top` is set to `height: 80px`.

Without a height limit on the sibling, content can visibly overflow (`overflow: visible` is the default setting), but `overflow: auto` needs a set height or `max-height` for scrollbars to work.

[revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gcdzL3jn/6/)

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 80vh;
}

#header {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
}

#main {
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#panel {
  height: 100%;
}

#panel-top {
  height: 80px;
  border-style: solid;
}

#panel-bottom-overflow {
  border-style: solid;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: calc(100% - 80px);  /* NEW */
}

* { box-sizing: border-box; } /* NEW */

#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="header">
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <div id="panel">
      <div id="panel-top">
        Top Panel
      </div>
      <div id="panel-bottom-overflow">
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a nested flexbox: `display: flex; flex-direction: column;` on `#panel` will also work ;) https://jsfiddle.net/gcdzL3jn/5/

Comment: Hmm, just woke up a quick sec., ... @Terry's fiddle doesn't have the red header and yellow footer visible in FF/Edge

Comment: @LGSon, yes, but that's related to another browser inconsistency. The header (red) and footer (yellow) need `flex-shink: 0` in some browsers. https://jsfiddle.net/gcdzL3jn/7/

Comment: I see that now, though as he gave `main` and `panel` a `height: 100%` his `panel-top` doesn't honor its `height: 80px` ... or am I missing something?

Comment: I couldn't sleep just yet....updated my answer with something that works :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I thought height could be inherited from parents, but it is not the cas as I understand, it has to be set explicitly

Answer (score 6):

By giving main wrappers, `body, #main, #panel`, `display: flex;` with column direction, the children that should take the remaining space (`#main, #panel, #panel-bottom-overflow`) `flex: 1` and finally add an extra wrapper for the scrolling, your will end up with this.

The extra `scroller` overcomes the issue where the overflowing element needs a height by using absolute positioning.

Note, this solution also makes it possible to drop the fixed height on both *header*, *panel* and *footer* (which I did, but you can of course add them back) and let it size by its content, and it will still work.

```css
body, #main, #panel {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#main, #panel, #panel-bottom-overflow {
  flex: 1;
}

body {
  height: 80vh;
}
#header {
  background-color: red;
  padding: 5px;
}
#main {
  background-color: green;
}
#panel-top {
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 30px 5px;
}
#panel-bottom-overflow {
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
}
#panel-bottom-overflow .scroller {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  right: 0; bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}
#footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  Header
</div>
<div id="main">
  <div id="panel">
    <div id="panel-top">
      Top Panel
    </div>
    <div id="panel-bottom-overflow">
      <div class="scroller">
        <ul>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
          <li>List item</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">Footer
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did not know which answer to accept, yours works as well, and is very elegant as it does not need to set explicit heights and resort to flexbox for fluid layout. Thanks a lot !!